# Codeigniter Login Form not getting my username and password

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I cant seem to login using these codes. Its not fetching the username and password on my database. Can you help me can i work with this? When login button clicked, it will validate if the username exist on the admin table and will check if the password is correct and status is Active. if so, it will go to the main page. if not it will stay on this page and display the error message. Please help

**In Controller**

```
  function login()
 {

//set validations
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "username", "trim|required|xss_clean");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "password", "trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database");

  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
      //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
      $this->load->view('login_view');
     //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username or password!</div>');
   }
  else
  {
 //Go to private area
 redirect('index','refresh');
  }

 }

  function check_database($password)
  {

   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $user = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->main_model->get_user($username, $password);
    $this->display($result);
    if($result)
    {
       $sess_array = array();
       foreach($result as $row)
    {
       $sess_array = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'username' => $row->username
         );
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
   {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username or password!</div>');
      return false;
   }
   }
```

**In model**

```
  function get_user($username, $password)
    {
           $sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $username . "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "' and status = 'Active' limit 1";
           $query = $this->db->query($sql);
           if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
             return $query->result();
            }
             else
            {
            return false;
            }
     }
```

**In View**

```
    <?php 
           $attributes = array("class"=>"login-form","id"=>"main","name"=>"main");
          echo form_open("main/login", $attributes);?>
     <body class="login-img3-body">

<div class="container">

    <div class="login-wrap">
        <p class="login-img">Login</p>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" autofocus>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="btn_login" value="Login" type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: any errors passing ??

Comment: no.. there are no errors.. i also tried to display the result i get from the sql query on my model but it displays nothing

Comment: is the page getting refreshed on click of submit button??

Comment: yes it refreshes when i click on the submit button.

Comment: you r redirecting to `index()`, show the code for that...

Comment: and also please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check if any error are there.

Comment: as you can see on my code, it will direct on the index() if the username and password is correct.. however, when i try to input username and password with correct values it stays on the login page and shows username and password incorrect. though its really the correct values

Comment: @Karl echo the query in model, copy that and run in phpmyadmin and see what  you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load the helper

in `__construct()`

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

In Model

```
function get_user($username, $password)
{
   $query = $this->db->query("select * from admin where username = '$username' and password = 'md5($password)' and status = 'Active' limit 1");
   $result = $query->result_array();

   $count = count($result);

   if($count == 1)
   {
      return $result;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

To submit form use this

```
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!', 'class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"');
```

Comment: white screen after click on submit ??

Comment: no.. it just stays on the login page after i click login button

Comment: Hi Abdulla, i tried all your advice but still got the same issue

Comment: did you change submit button too??

Comment: Yah, i already changed the submit button too.. its still the same

Comment: Actually i got the idea of the code here http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html everything is the same with the code on the link and my code.

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/create-login-and-registration-with-codeigniter/